# Can't use array of contracts inside a function in solidity

Tags: solidity

Can someone please explain me why this works fine

```
import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract storageFactoryContract {

SimpleStorage[] public asd;

function createSimpleStorageContract() public{
    
     
     SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
}

}
```

but this doesn't

```
import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract storageFactoryContract {

function createSimpleStorageContract() public{
    
     SimpleStorage[] public asd;

     SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
}

}
```

The error is:

> freecodecamptutorial/FactoryContract.sol:14:26: ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'public'
> SimpleStorage[] public asd;
> ^----^

Comment: Try delete `public` and set it `memory` or `storage`

Comment: It's the same, doesn't work

Comment: What error does it show?!

Answer (score 1):

In the second snippet, you're trying to set a visibility modifier for a regular variable. Only state variables (i.e. contract properties) and functions can have visibility modifiers.

Reference type variables (such as a `contract`) need to also have a data location. Since you're not working with the variable further, you can safely use the `memory` location. If you were to store it in storage, you might want to use the `storage` data location.

```
function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
     // removed the `public` modifier
     // added the `memory` data location
     SimpleStorage[] memory asd;
     SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
}
```

This will generate two warnings about the unused variables `asd` and `simpleStorage`. It's simply because you're assigning the variables but never using them later. In this context, you can safely ignore them.

*Note: I'm assuming that the `SimpleStorage` is a contract without a constructor or with a 0-argument constructor. Otherwise, you might get some different errors, for example wrong argument count.*

Comment: Great explanation sir, thank you !